# Is there a way in react-native to force a word to fit on the same line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As the title says is there any way to make a word in react-native stick to the same line?
Or if it's not big enough to fit on the same line to go on the next line

here's an example

```
Hello this is a verylo
ng word
```

to be

```
Hello this is a
verylongword
```

Answer (score 0):

hence the fontSize(**if you are paying attention to the diffrent screen sizes**)will be diffrent , the best way for handling that is putting a break line after the word you want a new line with .

as an example `<Text>Hello this is a {“\n”} verylongword </Text>` will do the trick

i hope it helps

Comment: The content is dynamic, I can't do that
I am trying to find a way to programatically make it go on the next line if it doesn't fit

Comment: you can easily check the text's length , if it exceed a number you can put a break!

Comment: Thought of that but it varies from screen size to size so it wouldn't make sense because maybe on one screen 50 letters fit and then on another 35 do fit

Comment: you can do it dynamically according to the height or width of the screen! for example: <Text>Hello this is a {width/10> 40 && text.length>30 ? “\n” :null } verylongword </Text>

Answer (score 0):

Use props numberOfLines in text. It truncate the text with an elipsis after computing the text layout, including line wrapping, such that the total number of lines does not exceed this number.

```js
<Text numberOfLines={1}> Hello this is a verylongword </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flexshrink` to make the text fit in a view or container

```
<View style={{flexShrink:1, width:20}}>
  <Text>Hello this is a very long word</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using [flexWrap](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#flexwrap) layout property should fix this.

```
<Text style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>"Hello this is a very long text"</Text>
```